# Comparing $\ce{PPh3}$ and dppe

Tags: coordination-compounds, crystal-field-theory

The ligands $\ce{PPh3}$ and dppe (dppe = 1,2-Bis(diphenylphosphino)ethane) are both strong field ligands, but is one obviously a stronger field ligand than the other or are they roughly equal?

The reason why I ask this question as I am researching into $\ce{[NiCl2(PPh3)2]}$ and $\ce{[NiCl2(dppe)]}$ and I trying to find another other reasons for the geometry difference other than sterics.

My guess would be that dppe is a strong field ligand, but that is more of a guess than any real logic application.